# Flutter: onTap is not triggering on Gesture detector which is in top of a Custom Paint Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, gesture, custom-painting

Here is my Widget

```
      child: Scaffold(
        body: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
          onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
            setState(() {
              RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
              pos2 = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
              listPos = List.from(listPos)..add(pos2);
            });
          },
          child: Stack(
             children: Widgets<>[
                 Container(
                    child: Column(
                       children: <Widget>[
                          GestureDetector(
                             onTap: () {
                                print('measure');
                                setState(() {
                                  toMeasure = true;
                                });
                             },
                            child: Icon(
                            Icons.linear_scale,
                            color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                   ],
               ),
                           CustomPaint(
                           painter: getWidget(listPos, pos1),
                           child: Container(),
              ),
           ),
         ],
       ),   
      )
    );
```

I am trying to switch to drawing into the area when user taps a icon. But once when the custom paint area is created when user taps the icon, it does not detect any tap after that.

The getWidget method is returning a widget based on the tapped icon.
This is one of the widget. When this widget is returned then the tap functions are not working anymore.

```
class Draw extends CustomPainter {
  List<Offset> listPos;
  Offset pos;
  Draw(this.listPos, this.pos);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    paint.color = Colors.greenAccent;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 4;
    var c = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    PointMode pointMode = PointMode.points;

    for (var i = 0; i < listPos.length; i++) {
      canvas.drawPoints(pointMode, listPos, paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(Draw old) {
    return old.listPos != listPos;
  }
}
```

Comment: create a sample with `GestureDetector` and `CustomPaint` only to narrow down your problem - whats the code of `getWidget` class?

Comment: getWidget(listPos, pos1) {
      if (toDraw) {  
        return Draw(listPos, pos1);  
  } else if (toMeasure) {  
    return Measure(listPos, pos1);  
  } else {  
    return null;  
  }  
}

Comment: there is no `Draw` and `Measure` classes in the official flutter SDK

Comment: No they are the classes i made. I have added the Draw class in original question above.